# Deserializing a CSV with Serde when the header row may not have the last column name in it

Tags: csv, rust, serde

I am using the `csv` and `serde` crates to deserialize csv files. The thing is that the last field is actually a comma separated list.

```
field1,field2,field3
xx, xx, str1, ..., strN
xx, xx,
xx, xx, str1, ..., strM
```

And this is how it maps in Rust, reading it with `.flexible(true)` on the reader:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Row {
  field1: isize,
  field2: isize,
  field3: Vec<String>,
}
```

Everything works fine if the CSV has the `,field3` the header row. But some of the files does not have it, and i can't find a solution to have serde still fill the `Vec`. All I was able to do is `#[serde(default)]` that just let `field3` empty.

Here a rust [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8e6fa29c5762bcc807f5a4ab9b22a189) showing the problem:

```rust
extern crate csv;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Row {
    field1: String,
    field2: String,
    #[serde(default)]
    field3: Vec<String>,
}

fn test(str: String) {
    let mut reader = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .flexible(true)
        .from_reader(str.as_bytes());

    for row in reader.deserialize() {
        if let Ok(row) = row {
            let row: Row = row;
            println!("{:?}", row);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let csv_data = "
field1,field2,field3
xx,yy,one,two,three
zz,ww,
aa,bb
cc,dd,foo,bar,ban
";
    println!("With full header");
    test(csv_data.to_string());

    let csv_alt_data = "
field1,field2
xx,yy,one,two,three
zz,ww,
aa,bb
cc,dd,foo,bar,ban
";
    println!("With incomplet header");
    test(csv_alt_data.to_string());
}
```

Comment: @Stargateur I added a rust playground to demonstrate the problem i have. This is exactly what you understood. the csv content is the same, but the "field3" column header is missing.

Comment: Is this really valid csv so ?

Comment: @Stargateur That's not the question, i have to support the case, it is not possible to go patch older revisions of the files in the source control. Thanks for inlining the code snippet tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the field header by the hand before read rows should do it, using [`headers()`](https://docs.rs/csv/1.0.6/csv/struct.Reader.html#method.headers) and [`set_headers()`](https://docs.rs/csv/1.0.6/csv/struct.Reader.html#method.set_headers):

```rust
let rdr = reader.headers().unwrap();
if let None = rdr.get(2) {
    let mut rdr = rdr.clone();
    rdr.push_field("field3");
    reader.set_headers(rdr);
}
```

However, that quick and dirty.

Comment: Works for me, i found i could also just `has_headers(false)` and skip the header row before passing it to the reader.

Comment: @galop1n That works too, but note that your struct will then be deserialized based purely on the order of the fields, and not by the names in the header. (Which might be okay for your use case!)